# Как ускорить выборку SQL?

Tags: оптимизация, выборка, mysql

```
mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `tasks` WHERE `id` NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)");

NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) - ведь когда будет много значений, выборка начнётся долгой.
```

Собственно какие есть пути, чтобы ускорить выборку(индексы стоят) или может переписать алгоритм исключения? Или моё мнение ошибочно?

Comment: А по какому алгоритму формируется NOT IN? Т.е. по какому критерию вы их исключаете?

NOT IN можно переписать как `id` != 1 AND `id != 2 AND ..., вроде должно быстрее выполняться, хотя не уверен - MySQL может оптимизировать запрос с константами и вызовы будут одинаковы по скорости.

Comment: NOT IN это тоже самое, что и AND `id` != 2, ну как же мне столько AND'ов наделать. Ведь вместо 1,2,3,4 стоит переменная $tasks_done

Comment: Так я отчасти из-за этого и спросил - по какому алгоритму формируется?

Ведь в $tasks_done вы как-то добавляете значения. Можно вместо добавления в массив добавлять в конец SQL.

Или заменить на другой запрос (возможно изменив немного таблицу как советовали в ответе).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

быстрее чем NOT IN (1,2,3,4,...) не получится. Даже на миллионах записей будет быстро делаться выборка если id у вас стоит или UNIQUE или PRIMARY

Answer (score 0):

В таблице `tasks` можно добавить еще одно поле, например, state, с разными статусами задания (скриптом его нужно будет менять) и выборку делать по нему.